# list inside .txt file wont convert into a list

Tags: python

I tried to make my code open a .txt file which contained a list inside and if you look inside the list all you see is the list, just like this "[3,5,6,6]" 
but when i open it i want it to end with dataset bieng the variable of the list and its value bieng a list to use in later code. the problem i am having is that dataset is bieng seem or its value is seen as a string not a list. i am trying to make this without using any modual or functions that would mainly do the work for me.

i tested a mini version on python shell where

```
f = str(f)
newlist = "f = " + f
exec(newlist)
```

it ended up with f bieng a list again but in this code dataset is still a string and not a list and i am very confused why it is not following the code like the other example. I also saved the list as a string in the other part of my code but in the .txt file i do not see quotations next to the list.

```
list_file = open((file_name+".txt"), "a")
list_file.write(str(dataset))
```

```
    loading = True
    while loading:
        file_name = input("Type below what the name of your file is\nLeave blank to go back\n:")
        if file_name == "":
            loading = False
            menu(dataset)
        else: 
            list_file = open((file_name+".txt"), "r")
            file = list_file.read()
            dataset = file
            newlist = "dataset ="+dataset
            exec(newlist)
            list_file.close()
            loading = False
            menu(dataset)
```

the result I wanted it to be was that it collects the list as a string and turns the string back into a list called dataset.

Comment: What's the output of list_file ? Something like `'[1,2,3]'`

Comment: You should use a proper data storage format such as [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) for serializing Python objects.

Comment: @JuanC the out put should be ```[1,2,3]``` basically a working list

Comment: @grooveplex the work i'm doing has to be a .txt file.

Comment: you could use [JSON](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) (instead of pickle) and dump it into a .txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn a string representation of a list into an actual list:

```
import ast
string = '[1,2,3]'
lst = ast.literal_eval(string)
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3]
```